# Dealing with collections from my model in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, custom

I'm trying to follow Alan Storm's tutorial [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access).

The code works fine when I try to insert or retrieve a single record, but it cracks when I use collections. I followed all  steps he illustrated in the tutorial, which drives me crazy because only collections wouldn't work!!

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Mymodule\Model\ConfigurationsFactory $myClass
) {
    $this->myClass = $myClass;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {

     $todo = $this->myClass->create();

     $collection = $todo->getCollection();

     foreach($collection as $item)
      {
        var_dump('Item ID: ' . $item->getConfigId());
        var_dump($item->getData());
      }
    exit;

}
```

This gives the following error:
 Vendor\Mymodule\Model\Configurations does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

The code for configurations model is as below

```
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Configurations extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Configurations');
    }
}
```

ResourceModel

```
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Configurations extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_configurations','config_id');
    }
}
```

Collection

```
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Configurations;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('
             Vendor\Mymodule\Model\Configurations',
            'Vendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Configurations');
    }
}
```

any hints would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can update the code lines of `Configurations` model?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh code added

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this very same issue and spent close to 4 hours trying to figure out the root-cause.

Turns out that there was an extra space (i.e. an `invisible` character) at the start of the my Model class specification in my `Collection.php` file 
( *File Location:* `Gsd\Punchout\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor` )

**Before:**

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(' ***Gsd\Punchout\Model\Vendor***', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Vendor');

}
```

**After:**

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('***Gsd\Punchout\Model\Vendor***', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyModel');

}
```

Posting the "fix" here in the hopes that it will help someone in the future.

In the code-snippet you've posted above, I do see a new-line character (i.e. invisible character) in the Model argument.

[image: Root Cause]

Once you fix that erratta, clear your cache and try again. It *should* resolve the issue.